# How to obtain the complete list of available Drush Output Formats?

Tags: drush

I'm trying to obtain the complete list of Drush Output Formats. I'm using drush 9.0-dev and in the [Output formats](http://www.drush.org/en/master/output-formats/) section of the [Drush Documentation](http://www.drush.org/en/master/) it says:

> The list of formats shown is abbreviated; to see the complete list of
>   available formats, run the help command with the --verbose option.

I tried `drush help --verbose`, but I can't find the information.

Is there another way to have access to this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the verbose list of output formats use `help` with a command name. For example the help for the watchdog list command `drush help wd-list`:

Normally you get:

```
 --format=<json>                           Select output format. Available: table, csv, html, json, list, var_export, yaml.
                                           Default is table.
```

But if you use `--verbose`:

```
drush --verbose help wd-list
```

You get the full list:

```
 --format=<json>                           Select output format.
                                           All available values are:
                                            - table: A formatted, word-wrapped table.
                                            - config: A configuration file in executable php format. The variable name is
                                           "config", and the variable keys are taken from the output data array's keys.
                                            - csv: A list of values, one per row, each of which is a comma-separated list of
                                           values.
                                            - html: An HTML representation
                                            - json: Javascript Object Notation.
                                            - labeled-export: A list of php exports, labeled with a name.
                                            - list: A simple list of values.
                                            - php: A serialized php string.
                                            - print-r: Output via php print_r function.
                                            - var_export: An array in executable php format.
                                            - variables: A list of php variable assignments.
                                            - yaml: Yaml output format.
                                           Default is table.
```

To get a global detailed list of all formats defined in drush you can use the drush function [outputformat_drush_engine_outputformat()](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/commands%21core%21outputformat.drush.inc/function/outputformat_drush_engine_outputformat/8.0.x):

```
drush ev 'var_dump(outputformat_drush_engine_outputformat())'
```

***EDIT:***

If you want to see only the format names you can use:

```
drush ev 'print_r(array_keys(outputformat_drush_engine_outputformat()))'
```

**Output:**

```
[0] => table
[1] => key-value
[2] => key-value-list
[3] => json
[4] => string
[5] => message
[6] => print-r
[7] => var_export
[8] => yaml
[9] => php
[10] => config
[11] => list
[12] => nested-csv
[13] => csv-or-string
[14] => csv
[15] => variables
[16] => labeled-export
[17] => html
```

Comment: and this is the full list for all the drush commands or only for the wd-list command?

Comment: I don't know exactly if it is about the help command, which can obviously only list the formats available to each command or to see which formats are available globally: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drush/tree/commands/core/outputformat